# Running PHP and Node.js on the same Nginx server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, php-fpm, node.js

is it possible to run PHP and Node.js on the same Nginx Server and VPS? I already manage to make nginx as reverse proxy for node.js but my question is how to run it alongside with PHP?

I want node.js to run on the subdomain let say `node.mydomain.com` while my PHP application runs on `mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this post: http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/

You could make a simple communicating script on `node.mydomain.com` and have the NodeJS server listen on another port.

Else you can also `proxy_redirect http://node.mydomain.com http://mydomain:8080/;` so here you have to run the NodeJS on another port, too.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this now on my DigitalOcean VPS.

Comment: Good luck dude :)

Comment: Thanks. I just did it. I created a virtual host both for PHP and Node.js. Then I just added `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000` to my Node.js virtual host configuration. It is now accessible.